# How to suppress messages from sys and os in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter

My question is similar to a bunch of other questions on this forum, but none of the solutions seem to work. I have a function which calls a command line function which print some stuff. I want this stuff not printed in my notebook. However, for the sake of reproducing let us use the function:

```
import os

def p():
    os.system('echo some_stuff')
```

If this function is executed in a jupyter cell, then `%%capture` or any of the other proposed solutions doesn't suppress it.

Secondly, `&> /dev/null` is not an option for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `os.system` doesn't let you control anything with the process, so it'll inherit the stdout handle and print to it directly, with your Python process not being able to do anything about it.

You should use subprocess which lets you control the child process' creation more, along with being able to view its output etc. if necessary. In this case you could redirect the standard streams to devnull, or if you need to interact with it using `subprocess.PIPE`.

As an additional bonus, subprocess doesn't run in the shell by default (although it can with the `shell=True` specified) which will be a tad faster and could be safer.

For example here the first process prints to stdout as it's not redirected anywhere, the second process' output is suppressed, and the third process' output is captured and accessible through the `stdout` attribute on the returned CompletedProcess object.

```py
In [90]: subprocess.run(["python", "-c", "print('printed')"])
printed
Out[90]: CompletedProcess(args=['python', '-c', "print('printed')"], returncode=0)

In [91]: subprocess.run(
    ...:     ["python", "-c", "print('printed')"],
    ...:     stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    ...:     stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    ...: )
Out[91]: CompletedProcess(args=['python', '-c', "print('printed')"], returncode=0)

In [92]: subprocess.run(
    ...:     ["python", "-c", "print('printed')"],
    ...:     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    ...:     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    ...: )
Out[92]: CompletedProcess(args=['python', '-c', "print('printed')"], returncode=0, stdout=b'printed\r\n', stderr=b'')
```

Comment: Thanks, I really hoped jupyter notebooks would have a way to cancel it out without touching `stdout`.

Comment: In what way? Specifying the stdout/stderr/stdin kwargs will not touch the streams of your python process. Though I believe that is how the capture magic works with a temporary redirect

Comment: There is a way to limit just touching stdout of your function using `with io.capture_output() as captured:`. You'd call your function on the next indented line following that. (The import for that is `from IPython.utils import io`.) Or there should be if all is working as it should. Your test example works with `%%capture` in that it doesn't show anything when it's used. Do you have something by way of a better test because there are other ways that should be working aside from subprocess, at least on a typical linux.